# Python 2.7: 'Ramón' == u'Ramón'

Tags: python, string, unicode, encoding, python-2.7

This returns **False**, because the first one is a **Str** object and the second one is a **Unicode** object.

However, since they are both *Ramón*, what can I do so that it returns **True**.

I've tried to convert the first one to a Unicode object:

```
>>> varString = 'Ramón'
>>> varUnicode = u'Ramón'
>>> varString == varUnicode
False
>>> newUnicode == unicode(varString, encoding='unicode-escape')
>>> varString; varUnicode; newUnicode
'Ram\xa2n'
u'Ram\xf3n'
u'Ram\xa2n'
>>> varUnicode == newUnicode
False
```

They have different encodings. What can I do? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`varString` is unlikely to be encoded in `unicode-escape`. The Python interpreter uses the encoding of `sys.stdin.encoding` when it decodes what it reads at the `>>>` prompt into a `unicode` object. So you can use the same encoding when you decode your `str` object for yourself:

```py
>>> import sys
>>> sys.stdin.encoding
'UTF-8'
>>> varString = 'Ramón'
>>> varUnicode = u'Ramón'
>>> newUnicode = unicode(varString, encoding='UTF-8') # or encoding=sys.stdin.encoding
>>> varString; varUnicode; newUnicode
'Ram\xc3\xb3n'
u'Ram\xf3n'
u'Ram\xf3n'
>>> varUnicode == newUnicode
True
```

Comment: When I write sys.stdin.encoding, I get 'cp850'. After that, I get an error when I write unicode(varString, encoding='utf8'). =/

Comment: @user1669007 You are supposed to use the same encoding as `sys.stdin.encoding`: `unicode(varString, encoding='cp850')`

Comment: Alright!! That works. Only one more question, how do I set 'UTF-8' to be the default encoding? Thanks again!

Comment: @user1669007 [http://superuser.com/questions/269818/change-default-code-page-of-windows-console-to-utf-8](http://superuser.com/questions/269818/change-default-code-page-of-windows-console-to-utf-8).